# VSCode not respecting tab size when formatting a Dart file

Tags: macos, formatting, visual-studio-code, dart, settings

I want VSCode on my Mac to use 4 spaces instead of 2 when I select Format Document. This is what I have on my User Settings:

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "Andale Mono",
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.detectIndentation": false
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme",
    "materialTheme.fixIconsRunning": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons"
}
```

However when I format the document, it does not respect the 4 spaces tab. It uses 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Dart plugin for VS Code. It uses the official [`dart_style`](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style) formatter which only supports formatting with spaces (the same as running `dartfmt`).

If you'd like to see a more flexible formatter, please put a ThumbsUp on this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/914

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was driving me nuts. Thumbs on the GitHub thread.